# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I'm using .Net 4.0 EF 4.0.

I have three tables in the database myentity, mygroup and myapplication. the myentity may belong to 1 to more mygroups and have 1 to more myapplications and mapped to the EF. I then have a myentityrepository class exposes a method as such:

```
    public MyEntity GetByName(string name)
    {
        var v = Set().Where(x => x.Name == name)
            .Include(x => x.MyEntityMyApplications)
            .Include(x => x.MyEntityMyGroups);
        v.Load();
        //v.ToList();

        return v.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

In my MVC controller.cs, I get the Name and filled my viewmodel with myentity object. After returned to the view page I got the error above.

```
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult GetMyentityAjax(string name)
     {
          MyViewModel uvm = new MyViewModel();
        using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new MyentityEntityContextFactory()))
        {
             Myentity me = _myentityRepository.GetByName(name);

            if (me != null)
            {
                uvm.Name = me.Nme;
                 ...                      
                 uvm.MyentityMyApplication = me.MyentityMyApplication.ToList();
                uvm.MyentityMygroups = me.MyentityMygroups .ToList();
            }
        }
        return Json(uvm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);         }
      //Even turned the lazyloding to false in //MydataModel.designer.cs as below
     public MyappEntities() : base("name=MyappEntities", "MyappEntities")
      {
        //#### CHANGE ME ######
        //this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        //#### END #####
        OnContextCreated();
      }
```

Please help. TIA,
-t

Answer (score 0):

After changed all three  this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled to false in mydatamodel.designer.cs, the exception gone.